# How to combine phase of one image with magnitude of another image in matlab and generate the inverse of the combined image

Tags: image, matlab, fft

I have calculated fourier transform of two images (`img1` & `img2`) and displayed its phase and magnitude. I want to merge the phase of `img1` and magnitude of `img2` and generate a new image. How can I generate the combined image and also calculate its inverse. Below is my code:

```
imagesc(img1); 
img1 = fftshift(img1(:,:,2)); 
F = fft2(img1); 

figure;  
imagesc(log(abs(fftshift(F)))); colormap(gray); 
title('magnitude Spectrum'); 
set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1],'units','normalized')  
figure; 

imagesc(angle(F)); colormap(gray); 
title('PhaseSpectrum'); 
set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1],'units','normalized') 

figure;  
imagesc(img2); 
img2 = fftshift(img2(:,:,2)); 
F2 = fft2(img2); 

figure;  
imagesc(log(abs(fftshift(F2)))); colormap(gray); 
title('magnitude Spectrum'); 
set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1],'units','normalized')  

figure; 
imagesc(angle(F2)); colormap(gray); 
title('PhaseSpectrum'); 
set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1],'units','normalized')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two images are of the same size, you can combine the magnitude and phase by using the following formula:

```
combined = abs(F2) .* exp(i * angle(F));
```

Then obtaining the inverse is simply a matter of using `ifft2` (perhaps followed by `ifftshift` depending on your application; I can't tell without more context whether you need to work with `fftshift`'ed images or not):

```
combined_img = ifft2(combined);
```

If the images aren't the same size, you should first obtain frequency-domain representations of the same size with the following:

```
m = max(size(img1,1), size(img2,1));
n = max(size(img1,2), size(img2,2));
F = fft2(img1,m,n);
F2 = fft2(img2,m,n);
```

Comment: That you for your help.I tried the same approach but since the magnitude and phase are of different images, the error of "Different matrix dimensions" is showing, What should i do in this case?